# Stripe: Get to know how many times webhook is triggered

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a requirement where I need to know what attempt it is when it is invoked. 
Consider the scenario below:

I have configured web hook setting as shown below:
[image]

Here I have specify configuration to invoke webhook 4 times in a month. My requirement is that I want to know that it is the 4th try. I have explored the request object of [charge.fail web hook](https://github.com/dpdexter/Stripe-Webhook/blob/master/webhooks/charge.failed). But couldn't find any configuration. Can anyone let me know how can I know about the retries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object) object would not have this information. The Charge is associated with an [Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object) object which is retried after each failure. The information lives on the Invoice instead under the property [attempt_count](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object-attempt_count).

You need to listen for `invoice.payment_failed` events instead or fetch the invoice via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice) otherwise when you get the failed charge event.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! This in`voice.payment_failed` webhook is triggered when payment is scheduled but not received right?

Comment: it is triggered when an invoice is charged and the charge fails yes